# Feature differences between shopify_app and shopify_api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

What I might be missing out by using the `shopify_api` library on a Rails API only site VS generating an app using `shopify_app`?

On the `shopify_app` github page I see things such as `WebhooksManager` , `ScripttagsManager` , etc. I am wondering if there is a subset of useful and critical tools I may need that does not come with `shopify_api` . Currently new and trying to learn the toolset

Answer (score 1):

I never used the Shopify App till recently, I only ever used Shopify API. I found it much simpler to get work done using Sinatra and rake tasks as a combo, perfect for a lot of Shopify work.

If you look into Shopify API, it is really ActiveResource tuned for the Shopify API. Now there is GraphQL too. Really handy stuff. Handling the security of Webhooks, App Proxy or Script Tags is a couple lines of Ruby code, so you decide if pulling in 250,000 lines of Rails (for Shopify App) is worth it.